# Requests.post error| TypeError: post() takes at least 1 argument (1 given)

Tags: python, python-requests, typeerror, jira-rest-api

I'm using Python 2.7.10 64-bit.
In the update_jira_field method, I'm getting the following error:

> TypeError: post() takes at least 1 argument (1 given)

I tried also `requests.put()`, combination of `json = payload` while declaring the payload as a json, but still got the same error.

I'm not sure what am I doing wrong, never experienced this error while using the requests module.

```
import requests
import json
import urllib2

auth = *****
propertKey = 'customfield_13557'
headers = {'Accept':'application/json','Bearer':****'}

def get_jira_real_id(jiraKey):
    endpoint = 'https://****.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/{0}'.format(jiraKey)
    response = requests.get(endpoint, headers = headers, auth = auth)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print "Success getting Jira Id"
        response = json.loads(response.text)
        return response['id']

def update_jira_field(jiraId,jiraKey):
    endpoint = 'https://****.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/{0}'.format(jiraId)
    payload = dict({"fields": {"customfield_13557":{"self": "https://****.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/customFieldOption/14915", "value": "Yes", "id": "14915"}}})
    response = requests.post(endpoint = endpoint, headers = headers, auth = auth, data = payload)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print "Success! Updated", jiraId, jiraKey

jiraList = ['****']
for jiraKey in jiraList:
    jiraId = get_jira_real_id(jiraKey)
    update_jira_field(jiraId, jiraKey)

print "Done Done Done"
```

Any idea why I get this error? and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You try to pass in a named parameter named `endpoint`, but the correct name is `url`. It whould work if you change the line to

```
response = requests.post(endpoint, headers = headers, auth = auth, data = payload)
```